# Missing data and negative predictions when kriging daily rainfall?

Tags: arcpy, kriging, missing-data

I want to perform the interpolation of daily rainfall data for 7 years. I am now working on python using arcpy module. I face several problems while performing interpolation

1. Some day there is no rainfall in all the station so that I am getting error for this issue.
2. After doing the interpolation I am getting some absurd values with negative values which is far from the real observation.

Is there a way to identify the parameters used for kriging interpolation?

I found that I need to change the parameters of the variogram for each day rainfall. Is this true?

Comment: On the days without rainfall, are your values Null or 0? You might think about filtering out those days for interpolation, but still capturing values of 0. Also, if you're taking measurements at fixed locations (rain gauges?), why do you need to interpolate for every time period? I'm just wondering what use you'd have with over 2000 interpolations for 7 years worth of daily data. I'm working on a tool to process time series elevation data, which could also be used for rainfall. I'll release on github in the next week.